# search files using group permission

Tags: permissions, zsh, wildcards

If i need to search files using group permission I use the following command

```
echo **/*(AIE)
```

where AIE stand for read/write/execute.

For owner and group permissions the qualifier used are rwx and RWX respectively.
What is the idea behind using AIE?

Answer (score 3):

The command argument of the example

```
echo **/*(AIE)
```

uses the glob sntax of `zsh`;
It does not work for `bash`, for example.

The characters in the `()` are glob qualifiers; Multiple qualifiers are combined by logical `AND` - that is, they all ned to apply.

So the command above shows filenames that are readable, writable and executable for the group.  They have the permissions that are set by `chmod g+rwx`.

A more portable way to search files by permissions is using the `-perm` test of `find`,
for example:

```
find -perm -g=rwx
```

Besides working independent of the shell, the syntax also tends to be more readable.

From `man zshall`:

```
Glob Qualifiers
    Patterns used for filename generation  may  end  in  a  list  of  qualifiers
    enclosed in parentheses.  The qualifiers specify which filenames that other‐
    wise match the given pattern will be inserted in the argument list.

    If the option BARE_GLOB_QUAL is set, then a trailing set of parentheses con‐
    taining no `|' or `(' characters (or `~' if it is special) is taken as a set
    of glob qualifiers.  A glob subexpression that would normally  be  taken  as
    glob  qualifiers, for example `(^x)', can be forced to be treated as part of
    the glob pattern  by  doubling  the  parentheses,  in  this  case  producing
    `((^x))'.

    If  the  option EXTENDED_GLOB is set, a different syntax for glob qualifiers
    is available, namely `(#qx)' where x is any of the same glob qualifiers used
    in  the  other  format.   The qualifiers must still appear at the end of the
    pattern.  However, with this syntax multiple glob qualifiers may be  chained
    together.   They  are  treated  as  a  logical AND of the individual sets of
    flags. [...]

    [ ... ]

    A      group-readable files (0040)
    I      group-writable files (0020)
    E      group-executable files (0010)
    R      world-readable files (0004)
    W      world-writable files (0002)
    X      world-executable files (0001)
```

See `man zshall | less '+/Glob Qualifiers'` or `pinfo zsh`

Comment: Thanks Volker. I should have also mentioned about zshell.